# Can a Matrix Have EigenBras?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra

I only need a yes or no, but I cannot find anything online. I know a matrix $A$ can have [eigenkets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Basis_states_of_one-particle_systems) found by using.
$$A\psi=\lambda\psi.$$
However, I was wondering if my matrix $A$ was [Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), could I just apply the [Hermitian conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) to the equation and find [eigenbras](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/lectures/node11.html) for the system too?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In fact: $$A |\psi\rangle = \lambda |\psi\rangle \Rightarrow \langle\psi|A^\dagger = \langle\psi|\lambda^*,$$
So, eigenbras and eigenkets are intimately related, which is why we normally just talk about eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to upvote but I need more comments or something to unlock that option :(

Comment: The inner product defines an isomorphism $V\to V^*$ and you obtained the equation on the right by applying the isomorphism to the equation on the left, didn't you?

Comment: @Filippo Yes. In physics we normally denote the Hermitian conjugate with a dagger, and the $*$ is used for complex conjugate.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation :) So we even have an equivalence.

Answer (score 4):

Look for left eigenvectors in linear algebra,

$v^H A = \lambda v^H$.

If the matrix is Hermitian, left and right eigenvectors are the same (just evaluate the conjugate transpose of the expression above to get $A^H v = \lambda^* v$; then you can prove that $\lambda$ is real as well).

Then ket goes to Right-eigenvectors, bra goes to Left-eigenvectors.